# How can I count the average number closest to 100?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where I got a list of numbers, gathered from a game where users have to click a button to get close to 100.

I thought I'd use `AVG()`, but this won't work obviously, because when you have 0 and 200, it will look as if you scored a perfect 100.

What I need is for every round (there are 10) count how far away from 100 the number is and count those.

```
Example:
User A: 98 + 102 + 102 = 6 (something) Loser!
User B: 95 + 100 + 100 = 5 (something) Winner!
```

What I had, but is obviously flawed:

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(score) AS Average, (100-AVG(score)) AS Difference, 
DATE(playtime) AS Playdate 
FROM playtable
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(playtime) 
ORDER BY Playdate DESC, user_id
```

Comment: I think you should have a subquery finding the differences, and then average that.

Comment: You'll probably want `SUM(ABS(100-score)) AS TotalDifference`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it

```
SELECT user_id, SUM( ABS(100-score) ) as cumulative_error,
  DATE(playtime) AS Playdate 
FROM playtable
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(playtime) 
ORDER BY Playdate DESC, user_id
```

cumulative_error will contain the accumulated difference values

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to fix your query to return the absolute value to see how far a score is from a given value (100 in your case)

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(score) AS Average, SUM(ABS(100 - score)) AS Difference, 
DATE(playtime) AS Playdate 
FROM playtable
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(playtime) 
ORDER BY Playdate DESC, user_id
```

Comment: I'd say you meant `AVG(ABS(100-score))`

Comment: As per the example, I think the op wants to sum the differences and not average them

Comment: Yep I think @Damp is correct. I've modified my answer but he beat me to the correct answer.